# How do i merge two subversion branches ( Merge Branch 7.3 to Branch RC )

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I have looked at [svnmerge](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py#Quick_Usage_Overview)  and regular svn, but the instructions either refer to merging branch to trunk, or the steps differ

Here is what i did, as far as svnmerge.py is concerned

```
mkdir MERGE
cd MERGE
svn co https://svn.hq.cod.corp/co/perlapp/branches/RC
cd RC-MOVEAPRIL13-1
svnmerge.py init

cd ..
svnmerge merge https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/7.3
Nothing happened

then:
cd MERGE/RC
svn merge -S https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/7.3
```

Now,  how do i know if 7.3 was indeed merged ? it happened very fast, so i think nothing happened.

Some advice to have a Temp RC branch, and merge to Temp RC branch, instead of the real target RC branch.

The other way, seems to be:

```
$ svn co https://svn.hq.cod.corp/co/perlapp/branches/RC
$ cd RC
$ svn merge --ignore-ancestry https://svn.hq.cod.corp/co/perlapp/branches/RC https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/7.3 .
# Check the diff to see if it merged properly
$ svn diff | less
```

Have not tried that

also:

svn merge -dry-run  -r 221381:259009 https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/7.3  https://svn.hq.cod.corp/co/perlapp/branches/RC gives error:

svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Cannot specify a revision range with two URLs

Keeping in mind that i want to merge FROM "7.3" branch, TO "RC" Branch, with the Final result as RC containing all commits to "7.3"

svn info URL :

```
kahmed@cr23788-kahmed:/media/Hitachi/3/SVN-MERGE-7.3_to_RC/RC$ 
kahmed@cr23788-kahmed:/media/Hitachi/3/SVN-MERGE-7.3_to_RC/RC$ svn info https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/build_7.3
Path: build_7.3
URL: https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/build_7.3
Repository Root: https://svn.hq.co.corp/co
Repository UUID: 1a64bf25-e0e5-0310-b6f3-de1d3c99dda3
Revision: 259054
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: mk
Last Changed Rev: 259009
Last Changed Date: 2013-07-05 11:45:26 -0400 (Fri, 05 Jul 2013)

kahmed@cr23788-kahmed:/media/Hitachi/3/SVN-MERGE-7.3_to_RC/RC$ svn info https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/RC
Path: RC
URL: https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/RC
Repository Root: https://svn.hq.co.corp/co
Repository UUID: 1a64bf25-e0e5-0310-b6f3-de1d3c99dda3
Revision: 259054
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: jc
Last Changed Rev: 259052
Last Changed Date: 2013-07-08 06:58:02 -0400 (Mon, 08 Jul 2013)

kahmed@cr23788-kahmed:/media/Hitachi/3/SVN-MERGE-7.3_to_RC/RC$ svn merge --dry-run http://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/build_7.3
svn: 'https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/RC' isn't in the same repository as 'http://svn.hq.co.corp/co'
```

Comment: UUIDs for both nodes are the same, I don't know now, why you get "isn't in the same repository". I'll hands up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to use **ordinary** merge (1-st form from `svn help merge`)
2. I don't know `-S` option for *any merge*

**Common pattern**

```
mkdir RC
cd RC
svn co https://svn.hq.cod.corp/co/perlapp/branches/RC
svn merge --dry-run https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/7.3
```

(inspect results, in case of "Tree conflict" have more thinking about resolving problem, in case of "Conflict" make pre-merge choice of correct version or merge in GUI-style with visual merger for resolving conflicts)

and...

```
svn merge https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/7.3
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, if this pattern would merge all revisions FROM 7.3 TO RC ( which is what i intend ) also is it possible to use svnmerge.py to keep a track of the merges across branches ?

Comment: @kamal - yes, "sync merge" merges all revisions in branch (or all after latest mergepoint, if mergeinfo used by Subversion />=1.6/). Merge tracking can be performed in more native way, read `svn help mergeinfo`

Comment: svn merge --dry-run http://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/build_7.3, gives me :
svn: 'https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/RC' isn't in the same repository as 'http://svn.hq.co.corp/co'

Comment: @kamal - ok, you must solve **this problem** first - I can't imagine, how you got this result. Both nodes must to have the same UUID (get it with `svn info URL`)

Comment: I am pasting the result of svn info URL in the question for proper formatting